# How to integrate Aftership API in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I am working on iOS App where I have to use Aftership SDK for tracking the order-details. While integrating aftership sdk with my app I am facing problem of app crash. I have followed their doc https://www.aftership.com/docs/api/4 also downloaded the SDK from the link https://github.com/AfterShip/aftership-ios. It is not get clear, how to use from its docs page to integrate this API and I haven't found any useful blog or article which would guide me to integrate this.

Also we need to use pods for installation. As I am new to iOS I am not getting how to use pods and make the SDK ready.

This is my first time working on these type of project so Can anyone please help me, to get this done. I will be very thankful.